# Resources ids.xml gives identical id Android

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I am having a weird problem, I set custom view's ids in the res/values/ids.xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <item name="observation_photo_view" type="id"/>
        <item name="path_view" type="id"/>
    </resources>
```

This should give unique ids to these strings.

Then I set the ids programmatically:

```
public ObservationPhotoView(Context context){
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setId(R.id.observation_photo_view); //setting it here
    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
}
```

And the same way for my custom path view.

However, when I try to get my ObverationPhotoView thanks to a

```
    (ObservationPhotoView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.observation_photo_view);
```

I get the error :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: CustomPathView cannot be cast to ObservationPhotoView
```

And after checking those views ids thanks to the debugger, I can see that they are indeed identical.
[comparing the two values via debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCCm1.png)

Is there any explanation to that?

Comment: (ObservationPhotoView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.observation_photo_view); what is parent view. share this code plz

Comment: It is another type of customView which is contained in a viewFlipper

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like a rebuild project worked, sorry for bothering.

I hope it'll help in case someone has the same issue.